# Looking for a pricing library supporting Mutli-curve Framework

Tags: yield-curve, irs

I am looking for a builder of Yield curves by tenors (O/N, 1M, 3M, 6M, 12M) respect to a given discount curve based on multi-curve framework as described below :

[Interest-rate Modelling with Multiple Yield Curves](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1006.4767v1.pdf) – *A Pallavicini, M Tarenghi – [2010]*

Do you know any pricing libraries that can meet my requirements and then proposes consistent pricing framework for IRS, FRA, IR options, etc ?

Comment: Take a look to this discussion: http://quantlib.10058.n7.nabble.com/Multiple-Interest-Rate-Curve-Bootstrapping-td17345.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quantlib supports multi-curve framework (to the best of my knowledge).
By the way, there's a "newer" version of that paper (authored by Pallavicini & Brigo).
http://arxiv.org/abs/1304.1397

[This](http://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2219548) paper might also be useful for you, very practical and basically answers any question you could have.

Also see [this](http://quantlib.10058.n7.nabble.com/Multicurve-discounting-td9444.html) discussion about multi-curve discounting within quantlib.

Answer (score 1):

There is a new book about this new topic:

[http://www.amazon.com/Interest-Rate-Modelling-Multi-Curve-Framework/dp/1137374659](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1137374659)

The author is a leading developer in Opengamma. Opengamma does have support for multi-curve building.